# Web Scraping Blocker with <p> tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Background:**
I am ultimately trying to web scrape a recipe website and collect key information inc. recipes - names, ingredients, prep instructions, cook time, prep time.
I am breaking this project into bite-size pieces. So far I have code that will scrape a recipe's web page for the ingredients.
**Where I need help:**
I am trying to evolve some code I wrote (it currently scrapes the recipe ingredients) so that it also scrapes the recipe steps (or 'Method' as the website refers to it as)
**CODE INPUT (1) -  for scraping ingredients (this works fine!):**

```
from scraper_api import ScraperAPIClient
from splinter import Browser
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

executable_path = {'executable_path': ChromeDriverManager().install()}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path)

resp = requests.get("https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cooking_for_two_strawberry_almond_oat_smoothie/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")

div_ = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "recipe-callout"})

recipes = {"_".join(div_.find("h2").text.split()):
               [x.text for x in div_.findAll("li", attrs={"class": "ingredient"})]}
```

**CODE OUTPUT (1)**

```
{'Strawberry_Almond_Oat_Smoothie_Recipe': ['1/2 cup uncooked old-fashioned rolled oats',
  '2 cups frozen strawberries',
  '1 cup plain yogurt (regular or Greek, any fat percentage)',
  '1 cup unsweetened vanilla almond milk (or milk of your choice)',
  '1/2 medium banana, fresh or frozen, sliced',
  '1/4 teaspoon pure almond extract',
  '1-2 teaspoons honey (optional)']}
```

**My research:**
Having looked at the HTML code for the same recipe website, I've identified the HTML I need to focus on - 
[image]
It looks like I need to target:

1. `<div>` with the `id="sr-recipe-callout"` and `class="recipe-callout"`.
2. `<p>` tags that have a `<strong>` element - annoyingly there are `<p>` that don't have `<strong>` and those are the ones that don't contain a recipe method and are useless.
   **Where I need help:**
   I have no idea how to evolve this code, specifically how I can condition that I only want to extract the `<p>` that have a `<strong>` element.
   I know this is a lot of information, but hopefully it makes sense and someone can guide me in evolving / recycling my current code, to fit the nuance of the HTML for Method, that it was for Ingredients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, "html.parser")
div = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "sr-recipe-method"})

# select all <p> tag's inside the <div>
for p in div.findAll("p"):
    # check if <strong> exist's inside <p> tag
    if p.find('strong'):
        print(p.text)
```

---

```
1 Combine the ingredients: In a blender, combine the oats, strawberries, yogurt, almond milk, banana, and almond extract.
2 Puree the smoothie: Starting on low speed, puree the ingredients. Turn the blender on high and continue to puree until smooth. Serve right away.
```